# gdal/geopandas data object compatibility in python

Tags: python, ogr, geopandas

Is it possible to convert an `ogr` datasource into a `geopandas` GeoDataFrame without writing the datasource first as a physical file and reading it back? I am referring to something like

```
import ogr, geopandas

drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('MEMORY')
source = drv.CreateDataSource('test')
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(source)
```

The above throws an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py",
>   line 47, in **init**
>       super(GeoDataFrame, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 422, in **init**
>       raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!') ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Which I get, no problem. However I find it hard to believe that you can't transfer data objects from `ogr` to `geopandas` and back without writing to physical files. What if you don't want to write a file because it is some part of an intermediate process you are trying to run?

Short of recreating the datasource feature by feature, geometry by geometry, field by field and, worst of all, transferring all the spatial reference data by writing custom wrapper functions, is there a way for `ogr` and `geopandas` to communicate?

Comment: 1) its not a layer, its a datasource. 2) trying `source.Reference()` throws error `maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: In reality the datasource is a result of the `gdal_Polygonize` routine. It contains polygons and attributes for each polygon feature. In the above example I simply create it without specifying a layer. It is a blank datasource, but thats just for demonstration purposes

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide details. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for necessary information.

Comment: What additional details would you like? I feel like it is a straightforward question....

Comment: The comments you have added should be merged into the question, then deleted.

Comment: Actually those comments where added as responses to comments by another user, who then quickly deleted them after asking for these details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GDAL memory driver is written for GDAL and obviously exactly for improving the performance https://www.gdal.org/drv_memory.html as you wrote. The documentation seems to suggest that other processes can't open a memory datastore.

> Memory This driver implements read and write access layers of features
>   contained entirely in memory. This is primarily useful as a high
>   performance, and highly malleable working data store. All update
>   options, geometry types, and field types are supported.
>
> There is no way to open an existing Memory datastore. It must be
>   created with CreateDataSource() and populated and used from that
>   handle. When the datastore is closed all contents are freed and
>   destroyed.

GDAL memory rasters https://www.gdal.org/frmt_mem.html can be opened. The difference is probably that for memory raster it is possible to define the offset where the data begins in the memory:

> It is possible to open an existing array in memory. To do so,
>   construct a dataset name with the following format:
>
> MEM:::option=value[,option=value...]
>
> For example:
>
> MEM:::DATAPOINTER=342343408,PIXELS=100,LINES=100,BANDS=3,DATATYPE=Byte,
>          PIXELOFFSET=3,LINEOFFSET=300,BANDOFFSET=1
>
> or
>
> MEM:::DATAPOINTER=0x1467BEF0,PIXELS=100,LINES=100,BANDS=3,DATATYPE=Byte,
>          PIXELOFFSET=3,LINEOFFSET=300,BANDOFFSET=1
>
> DATAPOINTER: address of the first pixel of the first band. The address can be represented as a hexadecimal or decimal value.
>   Hexadecimal values must be prefixed with '0x'. Some implementations
>   (notably Windows) doesn't print hexadecimal pointer values with a
>   leading '0x', so the prefix must be added. You can use CPLPrintPointer
>   to create a string with format suitable for use as a DATAPOINTER.